# How to get the continuous current rating of a power led from the spec sheet?

Tags: led, specifications

I am looking at an [Osram OSLON® Black, SFH 4715A Infared LED](https://www.osram.com/os/ecat/OSLON%C2%AE%20Black%20SFH%204715A/com/en/class_pim_web_catalog_103489/global/prd_pim_device_2219803/).

Is this LED rated for continuous operation?

The [spec sheet](https://media.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496376/SFH%204715A.pdf) lists:

> Total radiant flux (IF = 1 A, tp = 10 ms) (typ) Φe 770 mW

Does the 10ms mean that this is the maximum on time? Any way to figure out what the maximum continuous current is?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the graph for "Permissible Pulse Handling Capability?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in this chart on page 5 of the datasheet:

[image]

For pulse widths above 1 s, (which we can extrapolate out to DC operation), so long as you heat sink adequately to maintain a die temperature of 85 C (possibly slightly higher, but you definitely want to avoid run-away die temperature) the maximum current is 2 A.